# Is the VSCode marketplace showing wrong count of ratings for an extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, marketplace

I think the count of ratings for specific VSCode extension is strangely different from what I count myself.

For example, let's see the ratings page of this extension (Blockman):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leodevbro.blockman&ssr=false#review-details

Currently (2022-02-22) the number **88** is written at the top of the page.

You can click on "See more" at the bottom many times to load all the ratings the page provides, and run this script in browser console:

```
const listOfRatings = document.querySelector(".reviews-table");
const countOfRatings = listDiv.children.length;
console.log(countOfRatings);
```

And you will get the number 74. Also you can count the ratings manually on the page. I did both and I get 74 on both counting.

I don't think that too old ratings are hidden, because the date of the very last shown rating is the date when the extension was released.

Do you have any idea why the count number is different?

Answer (score 0):

I think now I know the answer. I discovered that the ratings page does not show the ratings which has empty comment. Here, left side is public page of ratings, the right side is the admin panel page of mine for my VSCode extension:

https://i.ibb.co/2jv8BCX/2022-02-22-11-17-42.png

.

.